# Loss of accents when inserting some UTF8 data into nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, utf-8, nvarchar

Create table:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StringsTest](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
```

Insert data (Latvian):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[StringsTest]
           ([Value])
     VALUES
           ('TĀDS KĀDU JŪS')
GO
```

Select:

```
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[StringsTest]
```

Results have lost accents:

```
Id          Value
1           TADS KADU JUS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `N` before your Unicode string to mark it as such.

```
 INSERT [dbo].[StringsTest]
       ([Value])
 VALUES
       (N'TĀDS KĀDU JŪS')
```